# Declare struct field name as "type"

Tags: go, struct

I am integrating API and parsing its response in a structure. For this I need to declare field name as `type` as API's response contains `key` named `type`. But when I declare `type` in field name it gives me error:

> syntax error: unexpected literal `type`, expecting field name or
>   embedded type.

I don't know how to declare literal `type` as struct field name.

My struct is

```
type Test struct {
    active bool
    name string
    description string
    amount  int
    currency string
    type string
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a field with name "type". You **must** rename it. No arguing, no workaround. Rename.

Comment: I can not rename it, as it is a key used in payment gateway's API response. Please help me with this.

Comment: For umarshaling an API response all you usually need is a tag.

Comment: E.g. `Type string \`json:"type"\``

Comment: Ok. Thanks @mkopriva. I will try

Comment: Anyways if you're using `encoding/json` or `encoding/xml` or other reflect-using-packages you'll need to change your fields to start with an upper case letter, otherwise the unmarshaling won't work. (user defined symbols starting with lower case letters are *unexported*)

Comment: "I can not rename it" _is_ arguing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your struct to this , to unmarshal api response *you need to export your structure's fields* i.e your structs feilds should be in upper case:

```
type Test struct {
    Active bool `json:"active"`
    Name string  `json:"name"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Amount  int `json:"amount"`
    Currency string `json:"currency"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

And then try to unmarshal your API response to this struct